# chef add a variable on cron resource

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to configure a cron job using cron resource in chef.

```
cron "execute_mytask" do
    action :create
    hour "0"
    minute "0"
    command '/bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
    /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron mytask "192.168.XXX.YYY" 
    >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1'
end
```

where 192.168.XXX.YYY is different between develop and production environment
It can either be a domain name or an IP address.

The problem comes when I am trying to change the command line with adding a variable/attribute. For example when I modify my cron entry to

```
command '/bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron 
  mytask "#{node["MyApp"]["IPAddress"]}" >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1'
end
```

then what I get in my cron job is

```
0 0 * * * /bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
/usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron 
mytask "#{node["MyApp"]["IPAddress"]}" >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1
```

so the best I could find was to hardcode it with the following

```
cron "execute_mytask" do
    action :create
    minute "*/5"
    case node.chef_environment
    when 'develop'
      command '/bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
      /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron 
      mytask "192.168.XXX.1" >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1'
end
    when 'production'
      command '/bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
      /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron 
      mytask "192.168.XXX.2" >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1'
    end 
end
```

Is there a way to add the variable/attribute in the command section of the cron resource?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes so the Ruby variable interpolation works:

```
cron "execute_mytask" do
    action :create
    hour "0"
    minute "0"
    command "mytask \"#{node['MyApp']['IPAddress']}\" >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1"
end
```

(FYI: Personally I prefer to use the `cron` cookbook with its `cron_d` resource which splits cronjob definitions in separate files. See https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/cron#readme - and I would render shell scripts that cover all tasks, like the time-stamp functionality in your example. It makes cron-files simpler to understand and you can manually test/execute your cron scripts)

Comment: Putting \" helped putting double quotes inside double quotes

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the way you are quoting your command, instead of using single ticks like you are now:

```
command '/bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron 
  mytask "#{node["MyApp"]["IPAddress"]}" >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1'
end
```

Use double quotes around the whole thing and possibly change your attributes to use semi-colons like:

```
command "/bin/date >> /var/log/mytask.log; 
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/index.php cli/cron 
  mytask #{node[:MyApp][:IPAddress]} >> /var/log/mytask.log 2>&1"
end
```

And then you can also avoid escaping characters like `"`

Comment: Using single ticks helped. Thank you